# As a pip install user, am I supposed to have wheel installed?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Consider the usual scenario - I want to create a virtual environment and install some packages. Say

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install databricks-cli
```

During the installation, I get an error

```
Building wheels for collected packages: databricks-cli
Building wheel for databricks-cli (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/paulius/Documents/wheeltest/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m7jmyh1m/databricks-cli/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-m7jmyh1m/databricks-cli/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-maxix98x
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-m7jmyh1m/databricks-cli/
Complete output (8 lines):
/tmp/pip-install-m7jmyh1m/databricks-cli/setup.py:24: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
import imp
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for databricks-cli
```

While it is benign (the installation actually works), it is still annoying.

I know that `pip install wheel` resolves this, but `wheel` does not come with the virtual environment by default. So should I always add it to my requirements.txt, or maybe this is something that can be solved by the package maintainer (in this case `databricks-cli`) and hence I should open an issue in their Github?

---

Update: note that the `wheel` is not necessary to install wheels, in this example bunch of dependencies get successfully downloaded and installed as wheels. The only databricks-cli package gets the error, as it does not have a wheel, but for some reason, pip tries to build it.

Comment: Have you tried installing the [wheel-file](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-cli/#files) with `pip install databricks_cli-0.14.3-py2-none-any.whl`? With that pip doesn´t need to build a wheel from source.

Comment: @KlimBim No, I have not. I expect pip to find the best file on it's own, without me searching for the approriate binary. (And I think it does that, in this case the wheel is for python2, so it is not suitable for my venv).

Comment: I am wondering why it isn´t working. If you install your downloaded `pip install databricks-cli-0.14.3.tar.gz` and `pip` doesn´t find `wheel`, it uses `setup.py` in the tarball. I tried it and `pip` used the legacy `setup.py install`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a pip bug, and the solution is to upgrade the pip. With the newest version things look fine:

```
(venv) paulius@xps:~/Documents/wheeltest$ pip install databricks-cli
Collecting databricks-cli
  Using cached databricks-cli-0.14.3.tar.gz (54 kB)
Collecting click>=6.7
  Using cached click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.17.3
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting six>=1.10.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting tabulate>=0.7.7
  Using cached tabulate-0.8.9-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for databricks-cli, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, tabulate, six, requests, click, databricks-cli
    Running setup.py install for databricks-cli ... done
Successfully installed certifi-2021.5.30 charset-normalizer-2.0.1 click-8.0.1 databricks-cli-0.14.3 idna-3.2 requests-2.26.0 six-1.16.0 tabulate-0.8.9 urllib3-1.26.6
```

Note the `Using legacy 'setup.py install' ...` line.

This is a related issue in the pip github https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8302. Not exactly that, but there is an explanation in the comments on what's the wheel building logic supposed to by.

Answer (score 9):

Update 3:

To prevent it from the maintainer's perspective use:

```
setup_requires=["wheel"]
```

it looks like you're on Linux and using the pre-installed or otherwise modified Python and its `setuptools`.

I've experienced the same thing due to Debian cutting off parts of the packages in not quite a sane way and I have mainly had issues with the prebuilt `python-setuptools` and likes. Check if the version matches and if not, install setuptools from pip, that might help in the future.

I have setuptools `45.2.0` and had no issues installing the package as a wheel. Then I uninstalled wheel and dropped the cache dir and it installed it properly even from [the `tar.gz` source](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-cli/#files).

Update 2:

It might or might not be resolved by requiring `wheel` package. If the `setup.py` expects `bdist_wheel` to be present prior to the installation (most likely), adding it to the `setup()` function will not help and a manual check for the package within the setup script (+ perhaps a reference in README) are necessary so an end-user can install it properly.

For example if it's not present on the system, just print a warning and call an `exit()`. That would be the least a maintainer should do.

---

Update:

Yes, in the case where you encounter `bdist_wheel` command missing you need to install wheel with `pip instal wheel`.

---

It's not required, but it's recommended. Pip will work just fine without wheels, but you'll be installing from source (`tar.gz`, `.zip` or `.egg`).

See [the packaging discussion](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/) for whether to use wheel or egg (or source).

Comment: I still don't quite understand. If I look at the setup.py of the example databricks-cli file (neat and small here https://github.com/databricks/databricks-cli/blob/master/setup.py) I don't see anything indicating that a wheel should be built, so why is it attempted and how should the maintainers prevent it?

Comment: Also see the Update to the question I made to clarify your first initial answer

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is not correct, and this is in fact a pip bug, that was fixed -- with pip 21.1.3 (newest) I no longer get the error, but a nice warning instead.

Comment: @psarka Seems like quite a new bug. I have `20.3.3` on one of the machines and I have tested it even there - no issues. I'm glad it works after the update though. Perhaps try to verify with `pip install --no-cache-dir`.

Comment: I get the error with `20.0.2`, so it must be somewhere in between. Thanks for the help!