# Python Azure Functions: arcgis package has egg-info instead of dist-info in Lib\site-packages

Tags: python, azure, arcgis, azure-durable-functions

I am testing an Azure Durable Function with the following `requirements.txt`:

```
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
datetime
requests==2.23.0 
arcgis==1.8.0.post1
openpyxl==3.0.3
aiohttp==3.7.3
numpy
```

When I debug it using VS Code, the `venv` is created adding all the relevant packages, but the Terminal complains saying `Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcgis'` despite this module being in the requirements file.

When I check the Troubleshooting Guide at https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound, one of the possible reasons they mention is:
[image]

However, when I check my `venv`, there is no `dist-info` folder, but only:
`arcgis-1.8.0.post1-py3.9.egg-info`.

Is there a way I can install the **wheel** instead?

Comment: Have you tried installing/upgrading wheel? `.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade wheel`

Comment: These might be helpful regarding `wheel` and `dist-info`:  [How to fix ".dist-info directory not found" in my package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270366/how-to-fix-dist-info-directory-not-found-in-my-package), [egg-info in local directory makes pip think package is installed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6558) and [pip uses egg-info instead of wheel dist-info for dependencies when installing a newly built wheel](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3214)

Comment: [As a pip install user, am I supposed to have wheel installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375133/as-a-pip-install-user-am-i-supposed-to-have-wheel-installed)

Comment: Hello @Zizzipupp, Is this issue resolved?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately